# Initialise date with hours / mins / seconds string

Tags: ruby, date

Given the string

> "00:00:25,123"

in the format

> "hours:mins:sec,milliseconds"

how can I create a date / time object which allows me to then add subtract seconds?

I'm not interested in the year, month, day, timezone etc. I just want to work with the hours, mins, secs and milliseconds components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do :

```
require 'time'

s = "00:00:25,123"
t = Time.strptime(s,"%H:%M:%S,%L") # => 2014-02-16 00:00:25 +0530
```

Then use [`Time#+`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-2B) to add/subtract seconds from `t`.

```
# add 20 seconds
t + 20 # => 2014-02-16 00:00:45 +0530
# subtract 20 seconds
t - 20 # => 2014-02-16 00:00:05 +0530
```

If you want to get the **miliseconds**, use [`Time#subsec`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Time.html#method-i-subsec), as below :

```
require 'time'

s = "00:00:25,123"
t = Time.strptime(s,"%H:%M:%S,%L")
t.subsec # => (123/1000)
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to ignore the milliseconds component. The +0530 is a timezone offset, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the date part, don't use a `Time` or `DateTime`, just keep track of the number of seconds as a float:

```
hours_str, minutes_str, seconds_str = s.split(':')
seconds  = seconds_str.sub(',', '.').to_f
seconds += hours_str.to_i * 60 * 60
seconds += minutes_str.to_i * 60
```